# converting LTR to RTL div class?

Tags: css, html

i am converting a theme into RTL. in the header two sections. left side logo area and right side contact area. now when converting this i want it logo in the right side and contact should move to left side...

style.css

```
<div class="span12 head_area"><div class="row">
<div class="span6 alpha">
<div class="logo_area">
<div id="widgets-reloaded-bizz-logo-2" class="widget logo"><div class="logo-spot"><div class="blog-title"><a href="http://bestdrive.co">Best Drive</a></div><div class="blog-description"></div></div></div><div id="transposh-2" class="widget widget_transposh"><span class="no_translate"><select name="lang" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"><option value="/" selected="selected">English</option><option value="/?lang=ar">العربية</option></select><br></span><div id="tr_credit"></div></div></div>
</div>
<div class="span6 omega">
<div class="contact_area">
<div id="bizz_cinfo-2" class="widget widget_cinfo">         <div class="contact-info">
                <div class="cblock c1">
<span class="pmeta">Email</span><a href="mailto:erbil@bestdrive.co"><span class="psmall">erbil@bestdrive.co</span></a>              </div>
                <div class="cblock c2">
<span class="pmeta">Call Us</span><a href="tel:+961 3 120 110"><span class="plarge">+961 3 120 110</span></a>               </div>
            </div>
</div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

If I make changes on `span6` it affects both `span6 alpha` and `span6 omega`. I also tried `float: right` on logo area. But it's not moving right of the window. It actually moves to right of `span6 alpha`.

I want `span6 alpha` on right side and `span6` omega on left side.

Where do I make the changes?

Comment: When you set the css selector to `.span.alpha` (no spaces), it will only affect an element that has those two classes together.

Comment: Tag wiki: "Register-transfer-level (RTL) abstraction is used in hardware description languages like Verilog and VHDL. *Don't use this tag for right-to-left.*"

Comment: @James I was quoting the tag wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at your code, it should just be `.alpha {float: right}` to get the whole group to move right and allowing the `.omega` to flow up to its left. Putting the `float` on the `logo_area` as you did would not have affected its relationship to the `contact_area` because each of those is self contained inside their respective `alpha` and `omega` wrappers.